# Why is Git not telling me that I am ahead of my remote

Tags: git

In order to synchronize my repositories with Wuala I created a new bare repository (which is synced).
I added this one as a remote to my existing (local) repo.

**Now I realized that `git status` should also tell me when I am ahead of my remote, but it isnt!**

```
C:\Users\blubb\Git Lokal\myproject>git remote -v
wuala   file:///C:\Users\blubb\Git\myproject-remote (fetch)
wuala   file:///C:\Users\blubb\Git\myproject-remote (push)
```

Currently I know that my lokal repo is ahead of the remote (local changes are commited), but that's the status I am getting.

```
C:\Users\blubb\Git Lokal\myproject>git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I am able to push my changes but it would be nice to see how many commits I am ahead to do a proper `rebase squash` before.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your branch may not be set up to track the remote. Try this:

```
git branch --set-upstream master wuala/master
```

And then see what `git status` says.

Comment: Yes...that did it. Thank you. I guess this setup happens automatically when I clone from the remote. 

Do I have to do this for every branch now?

Comment: If you create your branches via `git checkout wuala/<remotebranch> -b <branchname>` then they will automatically track `wuala/<remotebranch>`. If you create a branch that doesn't exist on the remote, you can use `git push -u` when you first push it to automatically set up tracking.

Answer (score 0):

--set-upstream is deprecated. The new syntax would be:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=wuala/master
```